# Idea Java Settings

Tags: java, intellij-idea, settings, java-5

In my project, I was using eclipse, but now I want to switch to Idea. But I have problems with Java setting. Our project is limited by java 1.5 (customer has websphere) so I tried to set all settings to SDK 1.5:

```
Project Structure -> Project SDK
Project Structure -> Project Language Level
```

I have only one SDK in Idea settings - 1.5

```
Settings -> Compiler -> Java compiler -> Project bytecode version - 1.5
Settings -> Compiler -> Java compiler -> all modules set to 1.5
```

But when idea starts compiling it says:

```
Information:Using javac 1.8.0_25 to compile java sources
```

This is from jre I found in \JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3\jre
And I dont know how to change it. This JREis also mentioned in about idea dialog.

My problem occurs when it try to compile (i think) groovy files. I get this exception

```
Information:Groovyc: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovycRunner$1.run(GroovycRunner.java:157)
at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovycRunner.buildMainLoader(GroovycRunner.java:155)
at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovycRunner.main(GroovycRunner.java:86)
... 5 more
```

I suppose that problem is somewhere in java settings but I really don't know where.

Comment: If you intend to use java JDK 1.5, it should be specified under Project Structure -> Project SDK. Can you verify what it says there, e.g. "1.8" or "1.5" and the text alongside it (java version xxx)

Comment: this is my project structure setting https://www.dropbox.com/s/60jq5owvu2a4ytw/idea.png?dl=0

Comment: Can you post a screenshot please instead of dropbox.

Comment: That looks OK. When you look at your modules (Project Structure > Modules), on the Dependencies tab, does each module use thie right SDK?

Comment: sorry for posting from dropbox but i haven't enough repoutation to posting images. :/

Comment: @Jasper Yes, every module has JDK set to 1.5